# Collapsing navbar content margin - span class bars

Tags: html, css, class, navbar, togglebutton

I have been working on this navbar template for a few days. Almost done, but it is not just as I wanted. Navbar is working fine, but how can I overcome spaces on four sides: 3px on the left (most probably 1px border+1px space+1px border)
10px on top, 10 px bottom, 33px on the right. Can you help me overcome them?

Second, `span` class bars are not showing, the same code works on another page? What am I missing?

Here is the example of my template:

http://jsfiddle.net/1hwbzk9v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.nav-justified {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1hwbzk9v/2/

Comment: Awesome. Thanx. The last thing. Span class bars aren't visible on Navbar toggle button? How to fix that too?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/1hwbzk9v/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/1hwbzk9v/3/)  - border added to `.navbar-toggle .icon-bar`